# MySQL STR_TO_DATE date works in SELECT but not in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I run my UPDATE statement, I'm getting an "incorrect date" error on my CAST statement. When I run the same query in a simple select, it properly converts to NULL.
I'm trying to capture and clean bad imported data in a MySQL 8.0 database and I'm using Mysql Workbench to run my queries.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
SELECT CAST(STR_TO_DATE('1/0/2000', '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE)
```

I get "NULL" as a result, which is what is expected. All good there.

Then, I try to update a table using that same logic:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblOne SET
NewDate = CAST(STR_TO_DATE('1/0/2000', '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE)
```

I get the error "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value '1/0/2000' for function str_to_date.

Obviously, I wouldn't hard code '1/0/1900' into my logic, but this is just to boil down the issue from the issues I was having with particular fields. I know I could run a query to specifically look for and remove '1/0/2000', but I'm looking for a bigger solution to capture any irregular value entered into the system. CAST seemed to fit my needs until this latest issue.

Here's a simple test:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.One ( 
RawDate char(50)
, CleanDate DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.One
SELECT '1/0/2000', NULL

SELECT RawDate, CAST(STR_TO_DATE(RawDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE)
FROM dbo.One

UPDATE dbo.One SET
CleanDate = CAST(STR_TO_DATE(RawDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE)
```

NewDate is a NULLABLE date field. As shown in the simple SELECT statement, the CAST should return a NULL. Instead, it seems to choke on the date in the UPDATE statement unlike how it does in the SELECT statement. What am I missing here?

- I edited this to be 1/0/2000 instead of 1/0/1900 because it was getting flagged as duplicate, but the issue is not because it is before 1970, but that 0 is not a valid day of the month.

Comment: `1/0/1900` is a bogus date.  Why do you want to handle such data?

Comment: STR_TO_DATE returns DATE already, so your CAST is excess...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm importing data from another source and the data is not clean (and can't be trusted for examples like the 1/0/1900 date). So, I'm trying to clean up the data. If the data is bad, I just want it to be NULL. In this case, I want 1/0/1900 to be translated to NULL.

Comment: MySQL implements more strict checking when you UPDATE/INSERT than when you SELECT.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. Strict or not, it should still treat a bad DATE as a NULL like it does with SELECT. How does how strict it is change what I should do?

Comment: What I mean by "more strict" is that it turns the warning into an error.